# django CreateView demands pk

Tags: django, django-views

this is my CreateView:

```
class LampCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Lamp
    template_name = 'shotmaker/test_cam.html'
    success_url = '/shotmaker/'
```

and its url:

```
url(r'^camera/create/$', views.LampCreateView.as_view(), name='lamp_create'),
```

when I try to open the URL I get this:

```
ValueError at /shotmaker/camera/create/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'create'
```

when I pass `pk` into the url:

```
url(r'^camera/create/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)$', views.LampCreateView.as_view(), name='lamp_create'),
```

the view opens ok.

Why does it need a pk if this is a CreateView? The `pk` is not supposed to exist yet!

Comment: Is that your complete view and url code? `CreateView` should not require a `pk`, and neither should the string `'create'` be passed to the view with the first url.

Comment: As another note to help with your code if you use `reverse_lazy` for the `success_url` you can use a named url, which is a general best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the full traceback, you should be able to see that it is not the `LampCreateView` that is raising the exception.

It sounds like you have another url pattern above the `lamp_create` which matches `/shotmaker/camera/create/` first. For example:

```
url(r'^camera/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', views.OtherView.as_view(), name='other_view')
url(r'^camera/create/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)$', views.LampCreateView.as_view(), name='lamp_create'),
```

To solve the problem, move the `other_view` url below the `lamp_create` url.

Comment: Or be more specific about what is accepted in the `pk` kwarg: it should be `\d+`, which wouldn't match "create".